# Generating git tree from git svn linear hierarchy with tags in subject

Tags: git, svn, version-control, merge, git-svn

So I have a problem, which I'm guessing is common to people who have migrated from svn to git, and I'm hoping someone has written a script to solve it, so I don't have to.

So when we used svn as our primary repo, branching/tagging was much more expensive, so we had 3 branches, development, qa and production, and tagged each production release.  So in day to day development, jira tickets were worked on on the current development head, and committed to that head with a title beginning 'JIRA: ABC-123' where ABC-123 identifies the ticket, where ABC is the functional grouping and 123 the ticket number.  In our model, functional elements from development would be merged into qa for testing (the tactical commits in development, became a larger strategic commit in qa), and the bug fixes to those strategic commits are added back to dev before being merged into a 'release branch' which was them merged back into qa and then production.

The git svn clone of development has (correctly) created a single long chain of commits leading back from the development branch.

However, I'd like to restructure that, such that all of the various modular commits, are separated into branches, which are periodically merged back into development, such that I should be able to go back and find a point in the development branch history, which is common to the current qa, production and development branches, from which I can rebuild qa and production branches, which ought to be basically development less a few feature branches.

I've manually gone back about a month, reverting tickets and comparing what I've got with the commit we created by manually diffing the files in the development branch with the qa branch, but that diff is just too big, for git to generate meaningful auto-merges.  I suspect my problem is there was active development in module A in november/december which went from dev into qa and so was released, whereas module B which was also being developed when into dev, but not qa/prod, and so I need to remove A and B from origin/master to create a common ancestor so I can add back in A generate qa, or A and B to get to the current development branch.

Now I accept there will be a degree of manual conflict resolution required, where commits A and B apparently in different areas, happen to change the same file, but I'm hoping git can cope with most things.  I've found in most cases when I ignore whitespace, diff's can be separated out, as long as they're done in sequence.

I suspect I need to use `git log --date-order --date=iso --format=:format:%H\ %cd\ %s` to generate something which I can read and from that script generating the instructions to split out all the commits into branches by module, from a common point, but having spent 2 days on this already, so I'm hoping someone else has solved this problem.  If not, I'll just have to solve it myself, and post the solution here so the next person can use it :-)

Edit

So looking at git rebase, I thought perhaps a diagram might help:-

I guess what I currently have is like this (with the ticket module/numbers underneath)

```
A---------B---------C---------D---------E---------F---------G
ABC-123   DEF-111   GHI-165   ABC-124   DEF-111   DEF-112   GHI-166
```

What I ideally want is

```
 C'--------G'
 GHI-165   GHI-166
/
A---------D'
ABC-123   ABC-124
\
 B---------E'--------F'
 DEF-111   DEF-111   DEF-112
```

And ultimately

```
 C'--------G'
 GHI-165   GHI-166
/
A---------D'
ABC-123   ABC-124
\
 B---------E'
 DEF-111   DEF-111
 \
  F'
  DEF-112
```

So that I can create a production branch, based on A(ABC-123), which only contains the B---E' branch (the DEF-111 ticket)

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind, that while I'm doing this, other developers are adding to G, so the longer it takes the more I have to fix.

Answer (score 1):

`git rebase --interactive` could probably be you main tool in this messy task. You can also do the split iteratively, e.g. start rebase for a particular line, pick the revisions (based on the comment I guess); when too many conflicts arise - `git rebase --abort` and try to reshuffle the history in smaller, easier manageable chunks.

**Edit** for example, to take the first branch `C-G` from the `development` line you gave, you could do following:

```
git checkout -b branchCG
git rebase -i A 
#remove all the commits except for C and G
#resolve possible conflicts
#at the end you have your C' and G' in constituting branchCG
```

now we'd want to clean the original branch, not absolutely necessary but can be handy to avoid mess with a long history

```
git checkout development
git rebase -i A
#remove/comment-out only the commits that you have picked for the branchCG
#resolve possible conflicts
```

at this point you have your develop without the contents of the branchCG and you may proceed with the next branches.

To leave the B as a parent for E' and F' you may either use it as a base point instead of A or just leave uncommented when doing both rebases. The latter option might not work if you have changes before B.

Comment: It's been a while since I used git as my primary revision tool, and from memory I avoided rebase like the plague, which I suspect is why I don't really remember how to use it properly.  I thought I could use it to essentially move the different modular commits to group them together on the line, so I could branch them off, but as they are all in a single long chained commit, how what are the options to move them down the chain, as ultimately wherever I opt to move them too, it'll always be an ancestor of the current position.

Comment: Rebase changes history, which might not be nice for the shared active branches, but you do want to change the history so there is nothing wrong with it. By "single long chained commit" I guess you mean long chained history with many unrelated commits - that would be a perfect job for the interactive commits, let me update the answer.

Comment: That looks good.  I just tried going back to an August commit to being a branch, and hit a .css conflict, so let me resolve that and see how I go with your solution, but it looks right.  I saw `git rebase --onto parent child1 child2` which looks like my way to split B and C off of A as branches.  In reality each branch is 20-30 commits and there are many, so I'm hoping it can auto-resolve most of the issues, or this is just going to be too time consuming.

Comment: Ok, so it didn't work.  I went to commit `2c7cc` A in our example, and created branch dev-origin, then commit `127aa` B in our example, and created branch BE, and commit `8a3f4` C in our example, and created Branch CG.  I then checked out CG and ran `git rebase -i dev-origin` and it popped up vim with a commit message, but once done, I'm back and the chain is still A---B---C

Comment: What I don't understand is, what should be my checkout in your example.  Now accepting that both B and C in my example change the same file, I found that `git rebase --onto A BD CG` causes a conflict (as expected), but `git rebase --onto A CG BD` doesn't.  That I don't understand, as I'd have thought changing C and B to make A their parent, should always create a conflict, or am I misunderstanding rebase.  Using your steps, I can't get the conflict that I should, and I cant get it to change C's parent to A.

Comment: @sibaz you may use the `-i` option to debug your rebases and see which commits does it apply in which order.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  In my current case I have a single conflict, as `A---B` changes several files including `f`. `B---C`only changes `f`.  `f` is a minified .css file, with a single line containing 33k.  I think the only difference is that by D, that line has a beginning, a middle and an end, where the beginning and the end is `A---C'` and the beginning and the middle is `A---B`.  interactive mode is no help what-so-ever in resolving or even identifying that.  In fact mostly unless I'm doing something wrong, as I don't even see a conflict, I don't think it's rebasing CG to A at all.

Comment: @sibaz this discussion has diverted way too far from the original question, so if something doesn't work as you expect you may ask a separate, more precise question. Rebases work very well and reliably. I am not sure I fully follow what kind of an issue are you getting, but `git rebase --onto A BD CG` and `git rebase --onto A CG BD` are not supposed to be performing the same action as they are very different. `-i` will not show you the conflicts but will show you the changes and the order of their application which most of the time will be enough.

Comment: OK, thanks, I think I misunderstand what rebase actually does then.  I thought my command would simply change the branches ending in BD and CG such that A is their parent.  I would have thought `git checkout -b branchCG` (putting you at the end of CG) followed by `git rebase -i A` would do the same, ie move CG ahead of BD.  I'm not sure how it could do that, without at least pointing out the conflict, and it doesn't seem to have done that.  Hence I assume I'm missing something.